# Return statement in python not working in sublime text editor

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run the following python function in sublime text editor

```
def match_find(data,target):


    for i in data:
        if i == target:
            return True
        else:
            return False

match_find([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],9)
```

The expected O/p here is false but the sublime text doesn't return the o/p.

Whereas when I tried the same code in jupyter notebooks, it worked fine.

What feature do I have to enable in sublime text editor so that it returns the o/p?

I have "Tools > Build System > Python selected
and
I have the "Tools > Save All on Build" option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issues with sublime, You code is having inconsistencies. the else would belong to the 'for' statement not 'if'. Use print statement to printout the value, currently just returning the boolean doesn't print anything

```
def match_find(data,target):


    for i in data:
        if i == target:
            return True
    else:
      return False

print(match_find([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],4))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now.... Im new to python ...Im just wondering why the "else" statement given to the if condition is causing inconsistencies

Comment: ```def count_match(data,target):
 count = 0

 for i in data:
  if i == target:
   count += 1
 return count

count_match([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],6)```

Comment: The above code also does'nt return anything...do you see any issue with the code here ?

Comment: your logic is to iterate through the array and check target is matching, if you return False in the first mismatch, the iteration will break. you don't have to do all this, if target in data: return true else return false will work fine. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-membership-identity-operators-not-not/

Comment: You should really ask a different question or modify the otiginal rather than use comments.

Comment: Sana, can you post a different question, I can't understand the code without indentations

Comment: Hi Ajay, sure , I have posted a new question for this ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844226/return-statement-not-working-in-sublime-text-editor

Comment: Hi Ajay , for your comment , you don't have to do all this, if target in data: return true else return false will work fine ====> thanks for the suggestion, but  its still not working in sublime text

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the function is to simply return if the data exists in the target then you simply need to

```
def match_find(data, target):
    return data in target
```

For count match you can use filter to reduce the list and len to get the size of the filtered list

```
def count_match(data,target):
    flist = list(filter(lambda x:x==data, target))
    return len(flist)
```

Comment: ```def match_find(data, target):
    return data in target```.  ===> Thanks for the suggestion, but the return statement is not working in Sublime, although it works in terminal

Comment: I don't understand this. Sublime is a text editor. Are you talking about debugging in sublime? I don't personally use this for developing python as I would use a full IDE, with integrated debugger. Using just a text editor for quick changes thin vi, nano or similar.