# Return statement not working in sublime text editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

```
def count_match(data,target): 
    count = 0 
    for i in data: 
        if i == target: 
            count += 1 
    return count 

count_match([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],6)


[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Expected output: `4`

Why does the return statement not work in sublime text editor?

Comment: just use vscode or jupyter notebook and make your life a breeze! specially if you are a beginner

Comment: @Rika because `return` statements will magically print the results in them?

Comment: No because those tools will help him/her achieve more with much less effort. Running that snippet of code inside vscode interactive python, would yield the result, just like in a jupyter cell. and he/she can experiment more and most likely catch errors or what he/she missed much much quicker. 
In any case sublime is not a good candidate for running/experimenting with python imoh. its just logical to use the tools tailored towards a specific goal to increase productivity and ease of mind!

Comment: I would counter that relying on an IDE rapidly results in a user who doesn't understand how the language works or how to work with the language on a machine not equipped with their IDE. Learning to use command-line tools and regular text editors teaches how to use the language on any machine and in any environment.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's being executed as a script, and scripts don't print anything implicitly. Simply print the return value:

```
result = count_match([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],6)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem with your text editor. The problem is you are  calling the function and not printing it.

Instead of

```
count_match([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],6)
```

use

```
print(count_match([1,2,3,5,6,5,6,6,6,4],6))
```

which will show your output returned by the function you wrote.

Comment: If Dcoder's answer doesn't solve the issue, Check if the  Python3 build system is selected on sublime. If its not, press Cmd+Shift+b to change the current build system.

Comment: The version of Python isn't an issue here; the OP's question shows the line that indicates that the build succeeded, the problem is 100% that the code is faulty based on the desired outcome.